# Is it possible to call aspx page via HTTP Endpoint in SQL server 2008/5

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to call (Post to) a Method in a ASPX (Code behind) page via HTTP endpoint in Sql server 2008/2005.

Comment: @gbn, I have a insert trigger on a db table, If an new entry inserted, I need to call a method  that implements a set of business rules (Essentialy creating Spread sheet containing data from the entry and other ...)

Comment: So, you want a trigger to make a call to a web page to read a sheet and iterate through business rules? YOu know the transaction will last for thee duration of the web call etc and absolutely kill performance and probably won't be reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP endpoints are first of all, [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28SQL.100%29.aspx). No new development should rely on them. Second, they have been, even for their brief lifetime, exclusively for *incomming* HTTP requests. HTTP endpoints can only serve a SOAP response, can never make an outbound call (GET or POST, mathers not). And last, all the points @gbn already made: never block a transaction on an outbound call. Do the business validation from a process call, before insert into the DB.

At worst, if no validation is possible before the insert, queue up a request for validation and place the data in a 'pending' state in the trigger, then commit. Then an external process can scan that queue and service the validation requests. You can [Use Tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/).

And no, CLR Web calls from triggers are no a solution (I'm sure some *will* mention them)...